# Reactor - Calling block on output of flatMap causes ClassCastException

Tags: spring-data, project-reactor

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 and Project Reactor. My issue is relating to some strange behavior encountered while writing a Unit test. I also ran into this while trying to feed the output of `flatMap` into the repository.

```
Mono<Foo> create(Mono<FooResource> resourceMono) {
    resourceMono.flatMap({
        // convert resource into Foo domain Entity
        return new Foo()
    })
}
```

This closure should emit a `Mono<Foo>` due to the return value of `flatMap`. However, when calling `block()` to subscribe and get the resulting `Foo`, there is a `ClassCastException` in `FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap`

Test code:

```
   def createdFoo = Foo.create(Mono.just(fooResource)).block()
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Foo cannot be cast to org.reactivestreams.Publisher

at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:141)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1161)
```

This appears to occur because `MonoJust` implements `Callable`, so `trySubscribeScalarMap` tries to unwrap it unsuccessfully.

In a non-test case scenario, a similar error occurs.

```
Mono<ServerResponse> createFoo(ServerRequest request) {
    def body = request.body(BodyExtractors.toMono(FooResource))
    ok().body(fromPublisher(Foo.create(body)
        .flatMap({fooRepository.save(it)}), Foo))
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Foo cannot be cast to reactor.core.publisher.Mono
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) [reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:450) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1092) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
<...>
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap] :
reactor.core.publisher.Mono.flatMap(Mono.java:2059)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:213)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
com.example.Foo.create(Foo.groovy:28)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
com.example.FooHandlerFunctions.createFoo(FooHandlerFunctions.groovy:48)
```

Wrapping the output of the `flatMap` closure in another `Mono.just(foo)` solves both issues. However, it seems like that shouldn't be needed. Am I doing something wrong or just misunderstanding how `flatMap` works here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `flatmap` takes a `Function` that should return a `Mono` (I guess groovy let you return the wrong type, as `Foo` doesn't seem to implement `Publisher`?)